# A name configuration on Heroku domain mydomain.herokuapp.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, dns

I have a heroku app mydomain.herokuapp.com and I have currently set up a cheaper deployment platform. I have some small number of users with their mobile phone app referring directly to mydomain.herokuapp.com

Is there a way I can set up an A name redirection from mydomain.herokuapp.com to XX.YY.ZZ.WW (my new deployment server IP)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do it, because heroku owns this domain (and the sub domain)

as a workaround, you can create a dummy  HTML file that will include

```
<script>window.location.href = 'xx.yyy.zzz'</script>
```

And this way all your users requests will redirected to the new server.